# Symfony2 : Echo in kernel.response event breaks cookies?

Tags: debugging, events, symfony, cookies, service

I had a weird problem with one of my Services, an event listener on kernel.response.

I wanted to set some cookies (*I need cookies instead of session for compatibility with Symfony1*) in it, and couldn't find how..

Until finally I understood that the code I wrote works except if I debug something in it (*like a `var_dump` of the cookies*).

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST == $event->getRequestType()):

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    var_dump($request->cookies->all());
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', 'bar'));

    endif;
}
```

So that wasn't working, my cookie was never in `$request->cookies->all()`.

But if I comment the `var_dump` line, refresh, and uncomment it, the cookie has been set !

Is it normal ? Why ? Does printing in an event like that break the headers ?!

Comment: Outputting anything anywhere breaks HTTP response headers being set afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Inject the `logger` service and use it

```
$this->logger->debug(print_r($request->cookies->all(), true));
```

Comment: I don't have access to `$this->logger` (I think?) because I'm in a `kernel.response` event.

Comment: Where did you configure your listener Bonsoir? In a services.yml or services.xml file I guess?

Comment: Yes, in a services.yml.
Do you mean I have to inject the profiler to each service I want to debug ?

Comment: Yes, everything you need (e.g. the logger) you have to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because doing the `var_dump()`, you "force" php to send the headers and so, when trying to set headers directly in your response, it doesn't work as they already have been populated.

Try doing the `var_dump()` after setting the cookie in the header.

Comment: Well yeah if I `var_dump` after the `setCookie` it works as expected, but the problem is that it doesn't prove the cookie has really been set afterward, just that this response object is working normally..

Comment: What about storing the result of `$request->cookies->all()` *before* the `setCookie` in a temp and dumping it afterwards?

Comment: If it works doing the `var_dump` after setting the cookie in the header, then I was right : the var_dump populates the response headers, that's why if you do the `var_dump` before setting the cookie in the response it doesn't work. I then second Pazi's comment : try using the logger to trace your data / actions. It's the "right way" to do debugging.